# Training deep learning models on Azure ML is extremely slow

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

Training a classification model on one V100 GPU (Standard_NC6s_v3) on Azure ML take couples of days which is extremely slow. Has anybody experienced that before?

I suspect that the data loading might be the bottleneck. However, I tried to copy the data from Azure blob storage into compute cluster docker container. However, it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

When using deep learning models, we need to create the compute instance with GPU. STANDARD_NV24 is suggestable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am using Standard_NC6s_v3 which has one V100 GPU and has higher compute copability than K80.

Comment: Can you mention the dataset size which is being used and the splitting distribution.

Comment: Same training takes 1/3 of the time on a local server